# Debug aspx.cs through web page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a question in .net Website.

**Note** : I am new in .net

I have made a website and checked it in my local IIS, and its working fine in local. But when I am deploying this website to server then I am not able to login

My code flow is:
 1. Created a Default.aspx with login id and password, then i am submitting it as follow

**Dafault.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server" name="loginForm" ng-controller="loginDetail as loginCtrl">
  <!-- For ID -->
 <input type="text" id="login_id" ng-model="login_id" class="form-control" name="login_id" placeholder="Enter Login ID" value="" required />
 <!-- For Password -->
 <input type="password" id="login_pass" ng-model="login_pass" class="form-control" name="login_pass" placeholder="Enter Your Password" value="test123" required />
 <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn-success"/>
</form>
```

Now JS is

**app.js**

```
 var app = angular.module("Admin",['ui.bootstrap']);
 app.controller('loginDetail', function ($scope, $http) {
     this.loginToolTip = "Press this to \bLogin";
     $scope.init = function () {
        document.getElementById('login_id').focus();
     };
     $scope.submitForm = function () {
     };
 });
```

and now backend code in default.aspx.cs is as follow

**Dafault.aspx.cs**

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.IO;
 using Newtonsoft.Json;

 namespace Main
 {
     public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
            string loginid = Request.Form["login_id"];
            string loginpass = Request.Form["login_pass"];
            List<User> allUsers = new List<User>();

            if (loginid != null)
            {

                try
                {
                    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("json/admins.json")))
                    {
                        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                        allUsers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json);
                    }

                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < allUsers.Count)
                    {
                        if (allUsers[i].Name.ToLower() == loginid.ToLower() && Base64Decode(allUsers[i].Password) == loginpass)
                        {
                            Session["User"] = loginid.ToLower();
                            if(loginid.ToLower() == "admin")
                            {
                                Response.Redirect("AdminUser.aspx", false);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx", false);
                            }
                        }
                        i++;
                    }

                    if (i == allUsers.Count)
                    {
                        //Check NonSuccess.
                    }
                    Session["AllUsers"] = allUsers;
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    //Some issue 
                }
            }
        }

        public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
        {
            byte[] base64EncodedBytes =     System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
        }
    }
}


public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I am reading from JSON.

This code is working fine in Local system. But not in Server. When I press Login button then Page should redirect to Admin/AdminUser Page. but it is just refreshing the page. I am unable to debug as well, in server side, as there is no Visual Studio. Also not able to find the exact issue.

Comment: any errors in web browser console?

Comment: no. because page got refreshed after pressing submit button. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Debug your code. You can write logs after any line where you want to debug. You can use this method:

```
public static void WriteLog(string LogStr)
{
    try
    {
        string LogFilePath = Server.MapPath("Logs.txt");
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(LogFilePath, FileMode.Create | FileMode.Append);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " | " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay + "=|" + LogStr);
        sw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

And call it like :

`WriteLog(json);`

Plus also check your `web browser console`.

Comment: Will this add log in Console or in a file in server?

Comment: @VarunJi in a file `Logs.txt` at server.

Comment: @VarunJi make sure `Logs.txt` exists.

Comment: I haved test it at my end by localhost url. But its not updating log. Do i need anything for this?

Comment: Did you created Logs.txt and called `WriteLog(json);` in your code ?

Comment: Yes, I did and log file size still 0kb and nothing is there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133566/discussion-between-varunji-and-afnan-ahmad).